# Row count no error, but wrong result

Tags: php, oracle

```
$rowcount = 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (select * from isk.edi_site where postal_code = 123456)';
$stmt= oci_parse($conn, $rowcount);
oci_execute($stmt);
$num_row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt);
$num = count($num_row, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
echo $num;
```

It counts and return the number "1". When I use the same SQL query in Oracle SQL developer, it echos out 4000+ count. Where would my mistake be? The column count works well..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `COUNT()` query only returns a single row so you need to grab it from the `oci_fetch_assoc()` call. What you're doing is counting the rows in the result set which will always be 1.

```
$row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt);
echo $row['COUNT(1)'];
```

Or give the count an alias:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) mycount FROM ...

$row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt);
echo $row['MYCOUNT'];
```

Comment: It doesn't work. You see, it told me that now "mycount" is undefined despite having it defined in my query as you said..

Comment: Show the result of `print_r($row);`

Comment: Array ( [MYCOUNT] => 4341 )

Comment: That looks fine, so try `echo $row['MYCOUNT'];`

Comment: Oh wait, it is the caps that is doing the problem. Silly me. Thank you so much for your help! I've been doing it all day. Thanks a lot!